# NoClassDefFoundError for NoContentException

Tags: grails, jackson-databind

I have a Grails 2.5.4 application using Jackson 2.4.5. I have a requirement to update databind to 2.13.1.

`compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs', name: 'jackson-jaxrs-json-provider', version: '2.4.5'`
`compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs', name: 'jackson-jaxrs-base', version: '2.4.5'`

Simply changing it to 2.13.1 gave me an error indicating I need to include something else. I added data-bind (that's the specific part I need to upgrade) so that now it looks like this:

`compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs', name: 'jackson-jaxrs-json-provider', version: '2.13.1'`
`compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs', name: 'jackson-jaxrs-base', version: '2.13.1'`

`compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.13.1'`

But now when I try to build it, I get the error `NoClassDefFoundError` for `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider` due to missing dependency `NoContentException`. I searched, and apparently `NoContentException` is simply a part Java, so I'm not sure what it means by "missing".

I found this thread that says a fix was put in 2.8.5, but, clearly that's not helping here. I also tried the `javax.ws.rs-api 2.0.1` bit near the bottom of the thread, but that didn't change anything either.